# How to say to hibernate that I really have transient entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity `O`, it contains entity `C` and `C` contains `Set<A>`. I know that `O` and it's "subentities" are transient. When I call `session.save(O)` hibernate will check if `C` and every `A` entity doesn't exist, because they have keys already filled in (not generated on database, also not generated through custom `IdentifierGenerator`.

Is there any chance to force hibernate not to check the state of these entities? I know if they are without keys (key columns are null) then it will know that only `insert into ...` is needed. But if I save that entity with `null` keys, I would not know how to generate their values.

Comment: A transient entity is a contradiction. Please post example code demonstrating the class setup you're talking about.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but POJO mapped with JPA or Hibernate annotations is usually called entity which could be in TRANSIENT->PERSISTED->DETACHED state

Comment: "Entity" is correct, but "transient" has a very specific meaning in Java, and the object before it's saved is just "not persisted".

Answer (score 0):

If `C` holds the foreign key to `O` and `O` is not mapped as cascading `save` or `updates` for `C`, hibernate should not check if `C` or `Set<S>` is persistent or transient when you call `session.save(O)`.

Comment: cascades are there and are necessary :( Only solution I can think of is very ugly. I can save that key column values in other class fields which are marked as transient and then in `IdentifierGenerator` just return them. But it really ugly and I'm not so sure that transient fields will be available at that time.

Comment: If they are there and necessary, you forced hibernate to check and perform the proper actions. Hence either you decide hibernate should do that for you or you prevent hibernate from doing it. I don't think you can do both at once ...

Comment: I know that hibernate should do it because of cascades. It just about optimization - I know that hibernate won't find a thing. I have there now `@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})` and if I understand it correctly - if I change ALL to everything but `save`, hibernate won't store entities `C` and `Set<S>` - but yes, hibernate will not look for their existence...

Comment: I just wanted to say to hibernate "hey man, this instance doesn't exist in DB, just save it, you don't need to look for it, if entity exist DB will fail and that's ok" and that would save me more than 3 selects per add operation. I probably have to look at it differently.

Comment: If `C` has an `id` different form `null`, hibernate deducts that `C` is persistent, and will fail if `C` does not exist in the DB. Otherwise, if `C` has a value of `null` for `id`, hibernate deducts that `C` is transient. If you mapped `O` to be compose of `C` and to cascade `saves` to `C`, hibernate will try to create `C` if it is transient. You may remove cascade `saves` from `O` and save `C` by yourself before saving `O`.